# reverse words , a pointer approach

Tags: c, generic-programming

I wanted to write a pointer based approach towards reversing a sentence by words.
I didn't want to use extra spaces or the usual approach so came up with a direct substitution approach.

I would like to get your feedback on anything i might have missed or if there's anything wrong with this approach.

```
int main() {
    char *s="lets test reverse";
    char *rev = malloc(strlen(s)+1);
    int slen = strlen(s)-1;
    char *sptr,*endptr,*prevpos;
    sptr = endptr = &s[slen]; //Mark end of string
    int i=0;
    int h=0;
    while(s[h] != '\0') {
        //Count how far is the first space from the end of the string.
        while(*sptr != ' ' && sptr > s) {
            sptr--;
        }
        // hold the refernce for future use.
        prevpos = sptr;

        //Once a ' ' is hit, move one char ahead to being copy.
        if(sptr > s)
            sptr++;

        // Copy ,starting from that word index till its end.
        for(sptr,i;sptr <= endptr;sptr++,i++)  {
           rev[i] = *sptr;
        }

        //If we've reached the start of the origString then dont add it back
        if(prevpos != s)
            rev[i] = *prevpos;i++;

        sptr = endptr = --prevpos;
        h++;
    }
    printf("%s\n", rev);
}
```

output: reverse test lets

Requesting feeback

Comment: This is a queation for [codereview.se]

Comment: What's the "usual approach" you're trying to avoid?

Comment: Initially reverse the individual words then revese that entire string.